# How to execute the constructor of a JavaScript class standalone

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object

I have a question that has been proven difficult for me to solve even using the resources online.

Given a class that has a constructor (or an object), how can I execute the constructor function independently without constructing a new object if possible? For example:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

Is it possible to execute just the constructor, without possibly creating a new object. For example,

```js
A.constructor.call();
```

But that does not work since class constructors need a `new` operator in front of them.

The reason I'm looking for this is that I have an object that has been previously constructed in a fashion similar to `const a = Object.create(A.prototype)` and I would like to "initialise" it, by calling the constructor directly on the object, hence reinitialising it like so: `hydrate(a)` where hydrate will call the constructor of the object directly using the constructed object like `a.prototype.constructor.call(a)`.

The closest I've been to a solution is by apparently utilising `Proxy` and `Reflect` like [this post](https://dev.to/adam_cyclones/simple-trick-to-instance-a-class-without-new-5e38) but it's not too clear for me.

Comment: Does your `a` already own properties that were added to it? If so, should the constructor be overwriting those? Then why have them in the first place? If the constructor should not overwrite those, then why do you need `a`? If `a` does not have own properties, why not recreate it by calling the constructor? Can you give a concrete example where you run into difficulties?

Comment: In the last paragraph you present an answer to your own question, but conclude it is not clear to you. So then what is the question?

Comment: "I have an object that has been previously constructed in a fashion similar to const a = Object.create(A.prototype)" then just don't do that and create it the normal way by calling `const a = new A();`. Whatever is preventing you from doing that is probably an easier problem to solve than this one. This is a neat question from a "how far can I bend the rules of the Matrix" perspective but isn't really something you should be looking to do in anything other than a toy example unless you have no alternative, and you probably have alternatives.

Comment: Constructors construct. It's what they do and they do it well (mostly - I've seen some poorly written constructors in my day). You probably don't want to call the constructor; you want to run some code that's written in the constructor. In that case, it's just poor design; either the class needs to be rewritten to move that code, or you need to reexamine how you're using the classes.

Comment: @JaredSmith I wish there were other ways of constructing this object myself. It's going to be a bit hard to explain since this is a very unusual situation but basically I have an object (not a JavaScript object) creating by other code (in this case C) and I get the object's pointer using ffi. now I'd like to construct the object after getting it's pointer and assigning it, think `a.pointer` and then call the constructor. it's a very difficult situation to explain and I'm hoping I'll find another way that doesn't involve hacking the constructor

Comment: @trincot I did not present an answer to my own question. I merely pointed out that Reflect and Proxy could possibly be used to solve this problem, but I pointed out that I'm not too familiar with their working, so I can't utilise them to solve my problem myself, hence resolting to asking the stack overflow community

Comment: That really doesn't make any sense either: why/how did the object in question get A's prototype if it is a C struct being passed to you via FFI? Did you call `Object.setPrototype` on it? Why do you have to mutate the C struct instead of just copying its properties onto an instance of A? Why do you have to use a class instead of a plain function that takes the C struct and adds properties to it? Again, the question you asked doesn't seem to match your actual problem, and since this one already has answers I recommend you ask a new one about your *actual* use case.

Comment: @JaredSmith Indeed. I mentioned the object has been called using `Object.create(A.prototype)`. The other questions are not easy to answer without providing you the full context, so I'll refrain from doing that and instead do as you recommend by creating a new question providing the full context and will make sure to invite you to discuss. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is always executed upon instantiation. If you want to execute the constructor when the object was already created, then the thing you want is not a constructor, but an initializer. Like this:

```js
class A {
  constructor(params) {
    if (params) this.initialize(params);
  }
  initialize(params) {
    console.log("initialized with: " + JSON.stringify(params));
  }
}

let a1 = new A(); //instantiated but not initialized
let a2 = new A({b: 2}); //instantiated and initialized
a1.initialize({a: 1}); //initialized an instantiated object
```

Answer (score 0):

*"A constructor constructs"*, or better instantiates; somebody mentioned it already. One mostly could relocate all the code, which unfortunately far too often gets squeezed into a constructor, to e.g. a `compile` function which the constructor just forwards to.

Back, in the old days [`RegExp.prototype.compile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/compile), for instance, provided such an experience. One could change the computational behavior of one and the same regex instance by using its `compile` method, where one then would pass other patterns/flags to.

An oversimplified implementation of `class A` looks like this ...

```js
class A {
  constructor(...args) {

    // forward to e.g. a compile method.
    this.compile(...args);
  }
  compile(foo, bar, baz) {

    // - compile might e.g. fiddle around with `this`
    //   in order to entirely mutate an instance.
    Object.assign(this, { foo, bar, baz });
  }
}
const a = new A('FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ');
console.log('constructed ... ', { a });

a.compile('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
console.log('re/compiled ... ', { a });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```